# Neo4j embedded in java out of memory (something wrong with cache)

Tags: java, neo4j, blueprint

In my research project, I partition my whole graph data into many parts, and store each part in its own graph.db folder
then, I may load 10 or 15  graph.db into memory at the same time( new Neo4jGraph(/path/to/graph.db) , I use blueprint api ), because I want to traverse on these part of graph which means if I can't find the node I want in this graph.db, I'll try to find it on other graph.db.

It works fine at first, but when it ran for a while, it'll throw these exceptions:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
  at java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReferenceArray.<init>(AtomicReferenceArray.java:94)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.cache.GCResistantCache.<init>(GCResistantCache.java:89)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.cache.GCResistantCacheProvider.newRelationshipCache(GCResistantCacheProvider.java:75)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.DefaultCaches.relationship(DefaultCaches.java:54)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.create(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:458)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:256)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:106)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:81)
  at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.neo4j.Neo4jGraph.<init>(Neo4jGraph.java:153)
  at netdb.graph.unit.CacheManager.loadGraphToCache(CacheManager.java:125)
  at netdb.graph.unit.CacheManager.findVertexInCache(CacheManager.java:67)
  at netdb.graph.opts.framework.IndexedGraph.query(IndexedGraph.java:47)
  at netdb.graph.opts.framework.run.OptsExecutor.run(OptsExecutor.java:62)
  at netdb.graph.opts.framework.run.OptsExecutor.main(OptsExecutor.java:129)
```

By the way, here is my jvm setting:

```
java -jar -Xmx90G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseNUMA
```

and neo4j.propertise:

```
neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=15G
neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=30G
neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=50G
neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=2G
neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory=2G
```

Does anyone know where should I look into? How can I avoid these error?
any advice are welcome

Thank you very much!

--------------update for code snippet ----------
[my code snippet](https://gist.github.com/ArvinH/9b9a4d38ce20758eb5c8)
maybe take a look at method loadGraphToCache

Comment: Share your code that you use, it seems that your cache fills up and uses all RAM. How much RAM do you have in total? What OS are you on? You cannot map 100GB for memory mapping and then another 90GB for heap if you don't have 200GB total memory.

Comment: Hi Michael, I have 96G RAM in total, and run on Ubuntu 12.04.
And actually I don't really understand what memory mapping doing for, so I not sure what volume I should config with. 
and the code related to create Neo4jGraph I update in my question.
Thanks for your help